# Javascript SDK Multi friend selector

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to install the fb multi friend selector using javascript SDK following this link :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

My question is : when i call the function :

function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

Its open a pop up with all my friend and send a message but when i go to Facebook and open this notification it open a wrong url :
http://mydomain.com/?request_ids=448697108486876&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user

So i wanted to know if it was possible to open a friend selector pop up and send a private message or a simple message on the wall to all friend users ? There is an existing code for that ? or i must develop my own code with Javascript SDK ? 
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the send dialog, if you had a multi friend selector and then the callback sent the array of selected friends to another function then you can call th send dialog, and put the callbacked users into the "to" field:

```
function sender(users_array) {    
  FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'Name',
      to: users_array,
      link: '<Some_URL>',
  });
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't works.. it works only for the first id user in the array.